# Why audio element currentTime on ffmpeg encoded mp3 file in Chrome browser does not work

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, mp3, html5-audio

I have an HTML5 audio element:

```
<audio id="mp3_audio_player" preload="auto">
    <source src="./Sound/recording.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

and I need to be able to play last 4 seconds from mp3 recording. My javaScript is:

```
audio.currentTime = audio.duration-4;
audio.play();
```

Works ok in IE10 and Firefox, but Chrome starts playing from a wrong place. The difference between reported audio.currentTime and actual playback position is about 20s. The recording.mp3 is created with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i recording.wav -ab 32k recording.mp3
```

It works, when I strip the ID3v2 header from the recording.mp3 (deleting the first couple bytes in the file before the audio data).

It also works when I compress to ogg. Can somebody point me to the right direction (ffmpeg switches, audio element attributes or whatever) to get it work also in chrome?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
the ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg version N-53528-g160ea26 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 27 2013 15:20:09 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 34.100 / 52. 34.100
  libavcodec     55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavformat    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavdevice    55.  1.101 / 55.  1.101
  libavfilter     3. 72.100 /  3. 72.100
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[wav @ 0433e840] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015510 microseconds
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'recording.wav':
  Duration: 02:30:07.86, bitrate: 176 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 11025 Hz, mono, s16, 176 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'recording.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf55.7.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 11025 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=   35188kB time=02:30:07.86 bitrate=  32.0kbits/s
video:0kB audio:35187kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.000672%
```

Comment: Please include the complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: Digging deeper into the problem, I found that the cause is not in the ID3v2 header. The clue is probably the Xing TOC, which I thought by mistake is part of the header. It is enough to remove only the Xing TOC or the frame, the ffmpeg puts insetad of Xing when CBR as in my case.